# split long method in different methods

Tags: php, refactoring, phpspreadsheet

I have this method:

```
public function createExcel(Task $task = null, Project $project = null, $projectTitle = null)
    {
        $this->spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();

        $default_border = array(
            'style' => Border::BORDER_THIN,
            'color' => array('rgb' => '1006A3')
        );

        $style_header = array(
            'borders' => array(
                'bottom' => $default_border,
                'left' => $default_border,
                'top' => $default_border,
                'right' => $default_border,
            ),
            'fill' => array(
                'type' => Fill::FILL_SOLID,
                'color' => array('rgb' => 'E1E0F7'),
            ),
            'font' => array(
                'bold' => true,
                'size' => 16,
            )
        );

        $style_content = array(
            'borders' => array(
                'bottom' => $default_border,
                'left' => $default_border,
                'top' => $default_border,
                'right' => $default_border,
            ),
            'fill' => array(
                'type' => Fill::FILL_SOLID,
                'color' => array('rgb' => 'eeeeee'),
            ),
            'font' => array(
                'size' => 12,
            )
        );

        /**
         * Header information of the excel sheet
         */
        $this->spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A1', 'Zoekterm')
            ->setCellValue('B1', 'Website')
            ->setCellValue('C1', 'Pagina')
            ->setCellValue('D1', 'Paginatitel')
            ->setCellValue('E1', 'Paginabeschrijving')
            ->setCellValue('F1', 'KvK-nummer')
            ->setCellValue('G1', 'Vestigingsnummer')
            ->setCellValue('H1', 'Adresgegevens');
        $this->spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:H1')->applyFromArray($style_header); // give style to header

        $dataku = [];


        if ($projectTitle == \BoolState::TRUE) {
            foreach ($project->tasks as $task)
                if ($task->status_id == TaskStatus::CLOSED)
                    foreach ($task->activeResults as $result)
                        $dataku[] = [$result->task->search_query, $result->page_url, $result->page_link, $result->page_title, $result->page_description, $result->coc_number, $result->branch_code, $result->address];
        } else {
            foreach ($task->activeResults as $result)
                $dataku[] = [$result->task->search_query, $result->page_url, $result->page_link, $result->page_title, $result->page_description, $result->coc_number, $result->branch_code, $result->address];
        }


        $firststyle = 'A2';
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($dataku); $i++) {
            $urut = $i + 2;
            $search_query = 'A' . $urut;
            $page_url = 'B' . $urut;
            $page_link = 'C' . $urut;
            $page_title = 'D' . $urut;
            $page_description = 'E' . $urut;
            $coc_number = 'F' . $urut;
            $branch_code = 'G' . $urut;
            $address = 'H' . $urut;
            $this->spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                ->setCellValue($search_query, $dataku[$i][0])
                ->setCellValue($page_url, $dataku[$i][1])
                ->setCellValue($page_link, $dataku[$i][2])
                ->setCellValue($page_title, $dataku[$i][3])
                ->setCellValue($page_description, $dataku[$i][4])
                ->setCellValue($coc_number, $dataku[$i][5])
                ->setCellValue($branch_code, $dataku[$i][6])
                ->setCellValue($address, $dataku[$i][7]);

            $laststyle = $page_description;
        }

        $this->spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($firststyle . ':' . $laststyle)->applyFromArray($style_content); // give style to header

        $writer = $this->outType == 'xlsx' ? new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx($this->spreadsheet) : new Xls($this->spreadsheet);
        var_dump($this->stream);
        if (!$this->stream) {
            $writer->save($this->filename);
        } else {
            $this->filename = $this->filename == null ? $this->title : $this->filename;
            $this->cleanOutput();
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="NVWA HDT ' . ucfirst($projectTitle ? $task->project->description : $task->search_query) . '.Xls"'); // file name of excel
            header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
            $writer->save('php://output');
            Yii::app()->end();
        }
    }
```

So the upper part is for then layout of the excel sheet. But is it cleaner to have that in a seperate method?

Thank you

if I do it like this:

```
<?php

namespace Scrape\domain;

$autoload =   DIR_ROOT . 'protected/extensions/phpexcel/Classes/vendor/autoload.php';
require $autoload;

use Yii;
use CWidget;
use Scrape\models\Task;
use Scrape\models\Project;
use Scrape\models\TaskStatus;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xls;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Border;


define('_SET_MEMORY_LIMIT_', '1024M');

class Downloader extends CWidget
{
    private $spreadsheet;
    private $task = null;
    private $project = null;
    private $projectTitle = null;

    private $style_header = [];
    private $style_content = [];
    private $dataku = [];
    private $stream     = true; //stream to browser

    private $outType = 'xlsx';
    private $filename   = null; //export FileName //false;
    private $title = '';

    public function downloadByTask(Task $task)
    {
        $this->createExcel($task, null);
    }

    public function downloadByProject(Project $project)
    {

        //var_dump($project);
        $this->createExcel(null, $project, true);
    }

    public function createExcel(Task $task = null, Project $project = null, $projectTitle = false)
    {

        
        $this->spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
        //var_dump($project);
        $this->initializeProperties($task, $project, $projectTitle);

        $this->setHeaderContent();

        $this->setMainContent($task, $project, $projectTitle);

        $this->doOutput();
    }

    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------

    PRIVATE METHODS

    -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /**
     * Initializes properties
     *
     *
     */
    private function initializeProperties(Task $task = null , Project $project = null, $projectTitle )
    {
        var_dump($this->project);
        $this->task = $task;
        $this->project = $project;
        $this->projectTitle = $projectTitle;

        $default_border = [
            'style' => Border::BORDER_THIN,
            'color' => ['rgb' => '1006A3']
        ];

        $this->style_header = [
            'borders' => [
                'bottom' => $default_border,
                'left' => $default_border,
                'top' => $default_border,
                'right' => $default_border,
            ],
            'fill' => [
                'type' => Fill::FILL_SOLID,
                'color' => ['rgb' => 'E1E0F7'],
            ],
            'font' => [
                'bold' => true,
                'size' => 16,
            ]
        ];

        $this->style_content = [
            'borders' => [
                'bottom' => $default_border,
                'left' => $default_border,
                'top' => $default_border,
                'right' => $default_border,
            ],
            'fill' => [
                'type' => Fill::FILL_SOLID,
                'color' => ['rgb' => 'eeeeee'],
            ],
            'font' => [
                'size' => 12,
            ]
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Sets the header information of the excel sheet
     *
     *
     */
    private function setHeaderContent()
    {
        $this->spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A1', 'Zoekterm')
            ->setCellValue('B1', 'Website')
            ->setCellValue('C1', 'Pagina')
            ->setCellValue('D1', 'Paginatitel')
            ->setCellValue('E1', 'Paginabeschrijving')
            ->setCellValue('F1', 'KvK-nummer')
            ->setCellValue('G1', 'Vestigingsnummer')
            ->setCellValue('H1', 'Adresgegevens');
        $this->spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:H1')->applyFromArray($this->style_header); // give style to header
    }

    /**
     * Sets the main excel content
     *
     *
     */
    private function setMainContent()
    {

        $this->prepareDataku();

        $firststyle = 'A2';
        $dataku = &$this->dataku; // define alias
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($dataku); $i++) {
            $urut = $i + 2;
            $search_query = 'A' . $urut;
            $page_url = 'B' . $urut;
            $page_link = 'C' . $urut;
            $page_title = 'D' . $urut;
            $page_description = 'E' . $urut;
            $coc_number = 'F' . $urut;
            $branch_code = 'G' . $urut;
            $address = 'H' . $urut;
            $this->spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                ->setCellValue($search_query, $dataku[$i][0])
                ->setCellValue($page_url, $dataku[$i][1])
                ->setCellValue($page_link, $dataku[$i][2])
                ->setCellValue($page_title, $dataku[$i][3])
                ->setCellValue($page_description, $dataku[$i][4])
                ->setCellValue($coc_number, $dataku[$i][5])
                ->setCellValue($branch_code, $dataku[$i][6])
                ->setCellValue($address, $dataku[$i][7]);

            $laststyle = $page_description;
        }

        $this->spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($firststyle . ':' . $laststyle)->applyFromArray($this->style_content);
    }

    /**
     * Prepares dataku array needed by setMainContent()
     *
     *
     */
    private function prepareDataku()
    {

        // Pay attention to "!=". This block is the else block in your code
        if ($this->projectTitle != \BoolState::TRUE) {
            foreach ($this->task->activeResults as $result) {
                $this->dataku[] = [$result->task->search_query, $result->page_url, $result->page_link, $result->page_title, $result->page_description, $result->coc_number, $result->branch_code, $result->address];
            }
            return;
        }

        foreach ($this->project->tasks as $task) {
            if ($task->status_id == TaskStatus::CLOSED) {
                foreach ($task->activeResults as $result) {
                    $this->dataku[] = [$result->task->search_query, $result->page_url, $result->page_link, $result->page_title, $result->page_description, $result->coc_number, $result->branch_code, $result->address];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Saves the generated excel file on the local disc or writes it to the output stream.
     *
     *
     *
     */
    private function doOutput()
    {



        $writer = $this->outType == 'xlsx' ? new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx($this->spreadsheet) : new Xls($this->spreadsheet);
        // var_dump($this->stream);

        # Save the excel file on the disc
        if (!$this->stream) {
            $writer->save($this->filename);
            return;
        }

        # Print the excel to the output stream
        $this->filename = $this->filename == null ? $this->title : $this->filename;

        $filename = "NVWA HDT " . ucfirst($this->projectTitle ? $this->task->project->description : $this->task->search_query) . '.Xls';
        $this->cleanOutput();
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . $filename . '"'); // file name of excel
        header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
        $writer->save('php://output');
        Yii::app()->end();
    }
}
```

then the

```
var_dump($this->project);
```

in the method

```
initializeProperties
```

it is not called.

```
Attempt to read property "project" on null
```

oke, in the method:

```
private function initializeProperties( Task $task = null , Project $project = null, $projectTitle = true )
    {
        var_dump($this->project);
}
```

is project null

but in the method:

```
private function doOutput()
    {

        var_dump($this->project);
}
```

I see the info for project.

I have a defaultController and in the defulatController there are these two methods:

```
    public function downloadByTask(Task $task)
    {
        $this->createExcel($task, null);
    }

    public function downloadByProject(Project $project)
    {
        //var_dump($project);
        $this->createExcel(null, $project, true);
    }
```

Comment: What is "cleaner" is very much subjective and questions that will only lead to opinionated answers are unfortunately off-topic here.

Comment: Oke, but I mean for the SOLID principle. And for testing. Is this method oke? Or it has to be refactored?

Comment: As a general, personal rule-of-thumb, any method longer than 30 lines is "too long". But this is the very definition of an opinion-based question.

Comment: You can split this method into 3-4 sub-methods. At the end you have your method `createExcel()` as a contoller, which should contain calls to other new methods. By this way you can see the flow on the top level, what and in which order things are done.

Comment: @mightycodeNewton I posted an answer, which may be interesting for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a suggestion. I do not know in which class is your method `createExcel()`, that is why I put all new defined methods and properties into MyClass.

Please pay attention, that this code contains simple refactorings like avoiding `array()` keyword in defining arrays. I also avoided to use `else{...}` blocks if possible by returning in `if{...}` block. By this way you can reduce the deepness of your if-else logic and the core becomes more readable.

```php
class MyClass {

    private $spreadsheet;
    private $task = null;
    private $project = null;
    private $projectTitle = null;

    private $style_header = [];
    private $style_content = [];
    private $dataku = [];

    public function createExcel(Task $task = null, Project $project = null, $projectTitle = null) {

        $this->initializeProperties($task, $project, $projectTitle);

        $this->setHeaderContent();

        $this->setMainContent($task, $project, $projectTitle);

        $this->doOutput();

    }

    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------

    PRIVATE METHODS

    -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /**
     * Initializes properties
     *
     *
     */
    private function initializeProperties(Task $task, Project $project, $projectTitle){
        $this->spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
        $this->task = $task;
        $this->project = $project;
        $this->projectTitle = $projectTitle;

        if($projectTitle == \BoolState::TRUE && !($project instanceof Project)){
            die("Project must be an instance of projectTitle set to TRUE!!!");
        }

        $default_border = [
            'style' => Border::BORDER_THIN,
            'color' => ['rgb' => '1006A3']
        ];

        $this->style_header = [
            'borders' => [
                'bottom' => $default_border,
                'left' => $default_border,
                'top' => $default_border,
                'right' => $default_border,
            ],
            'fill' => [
                'type' => Fill::FILL_SOLID,
                'color' => ['rgb' => 'E1E0F7'],
            ],
            'font' => [
                'bold' => true,
                'size' => 16,
            ]
        ];

        $this->style_content = [
            'borders' => [
                'bottom' => $default_border,
                'left' => $default_border,
                'top' => $default_border,
                'right' => $default_border,
            ],
            'fill' => [
                'type' => Fill::FILL_SOLID,
                'color' => ['rgb' => 'eeeeee'],
            ],
            'font' => [
                'size' => 12,
            ]
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Sets the header information of the excel sheet
     *
     *
     */
    private function setHeaderContent(){
        $this->spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A1', 'Zoekterm')
            ->setCellValue('B1', 'Website')
            ->setCellValue('C1', 'Pagina')
            ->setCellValue('D1', 'Paginatitel')
            ->setCellValue('E1', 'Paginabeschrijving')
            ->setCellValue('F1', 'KvK-nummer')
            ->setCellValue('G1', 'Vestigingsnummer')
            ->setCellValue('H1', 'Adresgegevens');
        $this->spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:H1')->applyFromArray($this->style_header); // give style to header
    }

    /**
     * Sets the main excel content
     *
     *
     */
    private function setMainContent(){

        $this->prepareDataku();

        $firststyle = 'A2';
        $dataku = &$this->dataku;// define alias
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($dataku); $i++) {
            $urut = $i + 2;
            $search_query = 'A' . $urut;
            $page_url = 'B' . $urut;
            $page_link = 'C' . $urut;
            $page_title = 'D' . $urut;
            $page_description = 'E' . $urut;
            $coc_number = 'F' . $urut;
            $branch_code = 'G' . $urut;
            $address = 'H' . $urut;
            $this->spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                ->setCellValue($search_query, $dataku[$i][0])
                ->setCellValue($page_url, $dataku[$i][1])
                ->setCellValue($page_link, $dataku[$i][2])
                ->setCellValue($page_title, $dataku[$i][3])
                ->setCellValue($page_description, $dataku[$i][4])
                ->setCellValue($coc_number, $dataku[$i][5])
                ->setCellValue($branch_code, $dataku[$i][6])
                ->setCellValue($address, $dataku[$i][7]);

            $laststyle = $page_description;
        }

        $this->spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($firststyle . ':' . $laststyle)->applyFromArray($this->style_content);
    }

    /**
     * Prepares dataku array needed by setMainContent()
     *
     *
     */
    private function prepareDataku() {

        // Pay attention to "!=". This block is the else block in your code
        if ($this->projectTitle != \BoolState::TRUE) {
            foreach ($this->task->activeResults as $result){
                $this->dataku[] = [$result->task->search_query, $result->page_url, $result->page_link, $result->page_title, $result->page_description, $result->coc_number, $result->branch_code, $result->address];
            }
            return;
        }

        foreach ($this->project->tasks as $task) {
            if ($task->status_id == TaskStatus::CLOSED) {
                foreach ($task->activeResults as $result) {
                    $this->dataku[] = [$result->task->search_query, $result->page_url, $result->page_link, $result->page_title, $result->page_description, $result->coc_number, $result->branch_code, $result->address];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Saves the generated excel file on the local disc or writes it to the output stream.
     *
     *
     *
     */
    private function doOutput(){

        $writer = $this->outType == 'xlsx' ? new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx($this->spreadsheet) : new Xls($this->spreadsheet);
        // var_dump($this->stream);

        # Save the excel file on the disc
        if (!$this->stream) {
            $writer->save($this->filename);
            return;
        }

        # Print the excel to the output stream
        $this->filename = $this->filename == null ? $this->title : $this->filename;

        $filename = "NVWA HDT ". ucfirst($this->projectTitle ? $this->task->project->description : $this->task->search_query) . '.Xls';
        $this->cleanOutput();
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . $filename . '"'); // file name of excel
        header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
        $writer->save('php://output');
        Yii::app()->end();
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, Thank you. I see it. But I have to modify something. But very nice. Because I have set all the properties. but I get this error: Attempt to read property "project" on null

Comment: But why you call the four methods in one central method?  I mean you can also call one method per metdho? Or is the way you suggest better?

Comment: @mightycodeNewton `Why I call 4 methods within the central method?` In that way you have overview over all sub tasks like in a flow chart. You can easily see what is done and in which order. `Attempt to read property "project" on null` In which line do you get this error? Maybe in the method `prepareDataku()` in foreach-loop?

Comment: @mightycodeNewton I answered your questions. Please tell me where the error occurs. Maybe you should guarantee that the parameter $project is set if `$projectTitle=true`. I guess that is the problem.

Comment: Hi Seim, I am using the Yii 1 framwork. But on the webpage I only see this error message: Error 500
Attempt to read property "project" on null

Comment: @mightycodeNewton I updated the method `initializeProperties()` with a check against the type of `$project` in case of `$projectTitle==TRUE`. According to your original code $project has to be an instance of `Project` class, if projectTitle is set to TRUE. There is only one place in the code, where `$this->project` is accessed and it is in `prepareDataku()` and `$this->project = $project` is set correctly in `initializeProperties()`. I believe the `Project` object is not passed to the `createExcel()` method. Please check for the correct place in the log file `protected/runtime/application.log`

Comment: @acar. But where can I find the application.log. Because if I look in what you suggest: protected/runtime. Then I see by me two folders: gii-1.1.21 and a folder: gii-1.1.22. and in those folders there is a file named: Modelcode.php: <?php
return array (
  'template' => 'default',
  'connectionId' => 'db',
  'tablePrefix' => '',
  'modelPath' => 'application.models',
  'baseClass' => 'CActiveRecord',
  'buildRelations' => '1',
  'commentsAsLabels' => '0',
);

Comment: @mightycodeNewton Hi, I sent you an e-mail just a minute ago.